# Why I obtain this error message when I try to set 2 foreign keys on a many to many association table? "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, rdbms

I am creating a database on MySql and I am finding some difficulties trying to set the foreign key constraint related to a **many to many** association table.

So basically I have these 2 tables:

1) **accomodation**: each record represent an hotel and have the following fields:

```
Field                                                            Type       Null Key Default    Extra                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                                                               bigint(20) unsigned NO   PRI            auto_increment             
user_id                                                          bigint(20) unsigned NO                                             
accomodation_name                                                varchar(100) NO                                             
description                                                      text       YES                                            
nation                                                           varchar(100) YES                                            
region                                                           varchar(100) YES                                            
province                                                         varchar(100) YES                                            
city                                                             varchar(100) YES                                            
stars                                                            int(10) unsigned YES                                            
geographical_position                                            point      YES                                            
accomodation_typological_id                                      bigint(20) unsigned YES  MUL                                       
accomodation_service_id                                          bigint(20) YES
```

2) **service** where each record represent a single service provided by an hotel of the previous table:

```
Field                                                            Type       Null Key Default    Extra                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                                                               bigint(20) NO   PRI            auto_increment             
description                                                      varchar(255) NO
```

Ok, then I have an association table named **accomodation_service** that implement a **many to many** relationship between the previous 2 tables, this is its structure:

```
Field                                                            Type       Null Key Default    Extra                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                                                               bigint(20) unsigned NO   PRI            auto_increment             
accomodation_id                                                  bigint(20) unsigned NO   MUL                                       
service_id                                                       bigint(20) unsigned NO
```

So, as you can see, this **accomodation_service** table associates a record of the **accomodation** table with a record of the **service** table.

My problem is trying to set the **foreign keys** in this table.

In the specific the **accomodation_id** have to contain only an **id** value of the **accomodation** table and the **service_id** have to contain only an **id** value of the **service** table.

So I have tryied to do it using the graphical tool provided by **Database WorkBanch 5** (my IDE), in this way:

[image]

but I am finding some dificultie because when I try to perform this constraint setting the IDE give me this error message:

```
#HY000Can't create table `testdb`.`#sql-417c_4b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
while executing:
ALTER TABLE accomodation_service ADD CONSTRAINT fk_accomodation_service_service FOREIGN KEY (service_id)
  REFERENCES service (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Why? Is it an IDE problem or am I missing something? What can I try to do to solve this issue? What query have I to perform to correctly set these 2 foreing keyes?

Answer (score 0):

accomodation_service Associate table not need new primary key "ID" as you defined.
you need to remove ID attribute from accomodation_service table and set "accomodation_id" and "service_id" as composite primary key.